# Is there any side effect of invoke channel.close() in initChannel()?

Tags: java, netty

I'm wondering if there is any side effect of invoke `Channel.close()` in `io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer#initChannel()`. It seems ok according to my simple test, but I don't know if there is corner case here.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely fine to do so. This will tear down the connection.